# C# Adding controls to a form from another class

Tags: c#, class, controls

Every time I create a new instance of `Player` I want to do the following code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Player Player1 = new Player();
}

Player class
{
    public Player()
    {
        Form1.AddControls(someControl)
    }
}
```

I can't seem to do anything to do with `form1` e.g. `textbox1.text = "Test"`. I assume this is a scope issue but I can't find an answer on the internet. Does anyone know how I can access + add controls to my `form1` through a class?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is not clear the context in which this code is located. Are you inside your Player class? And, if yes, have you passed to the class an instance of your form? Probably more code will be useful to understand your question

Comment: I hope my updated code helps. No i haven't passed an instance of the form to the class. I will try that.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where is the updated code..?? Ralt.. please add more code and make sure your format is readable..

Comment: I tried to psuedo as I'm not really sure how to go about this issue. There is the actual code that i currently have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. It sounds like you want to add controls from the Player class into the form that you're calling from like this:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Player player1 = new Player(this);
    }
}

public class Player()
{
    public Player(Form form)
    {
        Textbox tb = new Textbox();
        form.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I was trying to do yes. I was passing (Form1) instead of (this) though. This has solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome - you have to use "this" in order to pass through the current instance of Form1.