# C# Populating ListBox from another Class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have main window code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            UserName.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.UserName;
            PassWord.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;

        }
        //calling from click event atm because its easier to test
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Program.MyCall();
        }
    }
```

And now `class` with method :

```
public class Log
    {
       public static void MyCall()
        {
            MainWindow ControlForm = new MainWindow();

            ControlForm.Logger.Items.Add("Obtaining info ....");

        }
    }
```

I have a larger application and I want to make a log of events in an `ListBox`, so each time when `method` is executed I want to make a `log` of it in `ListBox`.
So basically above approach fails ... no error is generated but `ListBox` is empty.

Comment: You need to pass your form into the class. At the moment you are generating a completely new object. I asked a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896574/c-sharp-adding-controls-to-a-form-from-another-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you need to pass the form into the method so that you can access it, instead of creating a new one.

By creating a new one, you are no longer referencing the same form that you can see. You code is working, but it is updating a different instance of the form.

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Program.MyCall(this);
    }

public static void MyCall(Form form)
    {
        form.Logger.Items.Add("Obtaining info ....");
    }
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. You are passing a reference, but then ignoring that reference inside the MyCall function, needlessly instantiating another form, then calling the .Logger on the wrong object :)

Comment: @irreal Ah yes, forgot to clean up the method. Too eager to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is failing because you are instantiating a new form

```
 public static void MyCall()
        {
            MainWindow ControlForm = new MainWindow();
```

This creates a new form (which is by default **not** displayed on the screen), it does not reference the form that you already have.

There are multiple ways to interact with a from from the outside.
Possible solutions include passing a reference to the main form when instantiating other objects (or other forms), making the form use the singleton pattern where you'll only ever have one instance, which you can expose through a static property in the class, and so on.

No matter which way you pick to get a reference to the actual displayed form, you will also need to either make the List box public, or create a public function that accepts the data to be logged and adds it to the List box control.

Having said all that, what I would highly recommend is that you look into other logging frameworks that are available and pick one to use. For all but the most simple logging requirements, rolling out your own is not as optimal as using one of the existing and proven technologies. Once you implement one, you'll be able to look up it's documentation on accessing and displaying that data as needed.